# New PC build using latest 16.04 Ubuntu on AMD CPU

Tags: 16.04

This install is going on a SSD with 256 GB.
The machine has 8gb ram
These are on ASRock A350M- mobo.

Install takes ages to go through.
Once installed, nothing will work.
The mouse moves, however, it's like it hangs. No apps will open, nothing happens.
I can't open terminal to even see what might be a cause.

I've tried Ubuntu, mythbuntu.
I was thinking of trying 32 bit rather than 64.

Any other ideas appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running the Live Image from a USB flash drive or DVD/CD?

Comment: Yes, same problem.

Comment: Which AMD CPU? Is there a graphics card? Can you get to a text tty with Ctl-Alt-F6? Are you formatting the disk before trying different versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: CPU is AMD A10 9700. Onboard graphics. Formatting drive. Doesn't matter what I do, just takes a long time to do anything. Once the try or install screen is up, it can be 25 minutes until it recognises that you've pressed anything. I tried to install 32 bit & screen is completely screwy. I think it's the graphics, but can't get anywhere to be able to check